# Combine date and time fields to makeit datetime

Tags: oracle12c

I have 2 columns date(yyymmdd) and time (hhmmss) in string format.

```
dt           time
-----------------
20130218   000205
```

I am trying to make it to datetime.

using

```
to_date(to_char(DT, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' ' ||
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(time,'HH24MISS'),'HH2 4:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

but is not working.

Comment: up the error ....

Comment: the error is `unimplemented feature`

Answer (score 0):

Try to pay very close attention to what's a string and what's a datetime and what gets converted to what, when and why.

In the illustration below, `date_time` is in Oracle date datatype; it is displayed the way it is due to my session NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. (I could change it to display the time as well - it all depends on NLS_DATE_FORMAT.) In `d_t_string` I converted it back to string, with a very specific format model - the one you were attempting to use.

If you need this date to store in the database, or to use in further calculations, keep it in date datatype, do NOT convert it back to string. Do convert it to string, with a very specific format model, if you need to DISPLAY it (like I have done below).

```
with inputs ( dt, time ) as (
       select '20130218', '000205' from dual
     )
select dt, time, to_date( dt||time, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as date_time,
       to_char ( to_date( dt||time, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') , 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
                                                                        as d_t_string
from inputs;


Output:

DT       TIME   DATE_TIME  D_T_STRING        
-------- ------ ---------- -------------------
20130218 000205 2013-02-18 2013/02/18 00:02:05
```